# Add index weekday to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following data frame, which is indexed by `date_time`:

```
date_time               rsvp_limit  rsvp_yes    dropout                         
2017-11-30 19:00:00     240         229         0.045833
2017-10-19 19:00:00     300         300         0.000000
2017-06-26 19:00:00     300         300         0.000000
```

When I try to add `weekday` column to it, somehow it does not seem to succeed:

```
weekday_dropoouts = events['dropout'].copy()
weekday_dropoouts['weekday'] = weekday_dropoouts.index.weekday_name
weekday_dropoouts[:3]
```

Gives me:

```
date_time
2017-11-30 19:00:00    0.0458333
2017-10-19 19:00:00            0
2017-06-26 19:00:00            0
Name: dropout, dtype: object
```

What I'm trying achieve is to create a bar plot per weekday i.e. basically I'm trying to figure out which weekday the event experiences the highest drop out.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a type issue?

Is `weekday_dropoouts.index` definitely a `DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: If it weren't I wouldnt get the following output when displaying `weekday_dropoouts.index.weekday_name
`, right? `Index(['Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday', 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Tuesday'], dtype='object', name='date_time')`